# How to preserve version related metadata in archive while shipping

Tags: bash, tar, packaging

As the question says, I would like to know the best practice of how we preserve Version of the software while we are shipping in a form of Tarball.

I already use version in Archive file name, however it is lost when user unpacks it. Over some time, I won't even know which version of software user is operating on.

Looking for some sort of method such as MANIFEST.MF that java uses but didn't find anything with standard practice about it.

I can add to the build script to include that file and add version in the content every time I run the build script. But is there a practice already existing that I can use instead?

Comment: Most packages include the version in the directory contents of the tarball. See for example https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/; if you unpack for example `hello-2.12.tar.gz`, you'll find that it contains a `hello-2.12` directory.

Comment: embed version into the program itself https://github.com/rajeshsola/gnu-hello/blob/master/src/hello.c#L172